How to publish .NET application with Native AOT without Visual Studio on Windows?
According to Microsoft Docs, to publish your .NET 8 application on a Windows machine using Native AOT compilation, you have these prerequisites:

Visual Studio 2022, including the Desktop development with C++ workload with all default components.

I'm don't want to install Visual Studio, is there a way to make the publish succeed without installing it, like the prerequisites for Linux, only to install the necessary components? In other words, I'm looking for the components needed for succeeding a Native AOT publish and instructions for installing them manually.

I don't think you have to use Visual Studio to develop or even publish the app. You can still build in, say, VSCode and use dotnet publish from the command line. But you likely still need Visual Studio at least installed for the some of the components it includes.

Yes I know this @JoelCoehoorn, what I'm trying to do is to be able to manually install things Native AOT build needs, so VS2022 is not needed

Check out what Microsoft themselves do in their docker files for publishing an AOT application and you can either re-use that or copy it as a template.
curl -SL --output vs_buildtools.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe

vs_buildtools.exe --installPath C:\BuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041 --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache

dotnet publish -o /app HelloWorld.csproj

Note: Use of the Visual Studio Build Tools requires a valid Visual Studio license.
This link is for Windows:
https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/main/core/nativeaot/HelloWorld/Dockerfile.windowsservercore-x64

This should be accepted as the best answer. It is an actual functional resolution.

According to MS:

Visual Studio 2022 Preview is required because Native AOT requires link.exe and the Visual C++ static runtime libraries. There are no plans to support Native AOT without Visual Studio.

So maybe if you can isolate required components, then it would be possible without actual VS installation.

Are you sure that these libraries are only required?
